# Outer product in CVXPY

Tags: python, numpy, cvxpy

I have an objective function that depends on a sum of outer products. If I could use Numpy functions, I would write this as:

```
A = np.ones(m, n)
U = Variable(m, n)
objective = np.trace(sum([np.outer(A[i,:], U[i,:]) for i in range(m)]))
```

Of course np.outer doesn't work when U is a variable. Is there a cvxpy affine function that would implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cvxpy has a kron function that works. Since it only works on 2d Variables and 2d-arrays, you have to reshape the vectors to (n, 1) vectors first:

```
cvx.trace(sum([cvx.kron(A[i, :].reshape(n,1), cvx.reshape(U[i,:], (n,1))
               for i in range(m)]))
```

Another solution would be to simply write the matrix product:

```
cvx.trace(sum([A[i, :].reshape(n, 1) @ cvx.reshape(U[i,:], (1, n)
               for i in range(m)]))
```

Comment: Could you give an example that's similar to numpy's outer function? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html?highlight=outer#numpy.outer